# Rails 3.0 apps (after rails 3.1 install) now give error with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

getting a message
You have already activated rake 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.

saw references to "update the standard Ruby installation from Rake 0.8.7 to Rake 0.9.2"

how do I do this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `bundle update rake`

This will update rake and resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You want to your commands with "bundle exec " without the double quotes